# Is it possible to make a validation with JavaScript on this JSP form?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, jsp

Want to make a validation of this JSP form

#### JSP

```
   <form:form action="saveEmpleado" method="post" modelAttribute="empleado">
            <table border="1" class="table-fill">
                <form:hidden path="id"/>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><form:input id="email" path="email"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Guardar"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

I tried with this but wont work, what im doing wrong?

#### JavaScript

```
window.onload = iniciar;

function iniciar() {
    document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click', validar, false);
}

function validar() {
    validarEmail();
}

function validarEmail() {
    var elemento = document.getElementById('email');
    var regx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (!regx.test(elemento))) {
        alert("Error");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here simply you can cal onclick function on the submit button.And there is an extra bracket in the if condition `( if (!regx.test(elemento)) )`

JSP :

```
<form:form action="saveEmpleado" method="post" modelAttribute="empleado">
            <table border="1" class="table-fill">
                <form:hidden path="id"/>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><form:input id="email" path="email"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Guardar" onclick="validarEmail();"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
function validarEmail() {
    var elemento = document.getElementById('email');
    var regx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (!regx.test(elemento)) {
        alert("Error");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```